# How to copy using scp on shell script to folders space named?

Tags: shell, directory, scp

Hey guys I am working on this app that connects to Raspberry Pi through SSH. I use NSTask and NSPipe and shell scripts to execute the shell commands through the Mac app GUI.

The problem is that when I want to copy using "scp" command I get "No such file or directory" error with folders with spaces on its name. If the path is "/Users/home/Desktop/New Files/" doesn't work, but if "/Users/home/Desktop/New Files/" works fine.

The app must be able to use both, separated named folders and not separated, but I just don't know how to do it.

Here is my shell script command:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh pi@192.168.25.144 \
/usr/bin/scp /home/pi/"${1}" home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/New Files/
```

The "X"on the ip was intentionally removed and it's not on the real code.

So, anyone could help????

Comment: You realize that 192.168.0.0/16  is a private, non publicly-routable range, and there's no point in obfuscating it right?

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code of what you have tried.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart sorry but I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @rmaddy the code I tried is already within the question is it?

Comment: I don't see any Objective-C code in your question. Also, did you try preceding any spaces in the path with a backslash?

Comment: @rmaddy but the problem is not with the objective-c code, that's why I didn't post any of it. And yes I have tried using backslash that and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because it requires multiple levels of escaping.

First, start with the actual path:

```
home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/New Files/
```

Now escape it for the shell:

```
"home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/New Files/"
```

Now escape it for scp, since scp accepts shell glob patterns and not filenames:

```
/usr/bin/scp /home/pi/"${1}" "home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/New\\ Files/"
```

Now escape it for ssh, since ssh will evaluate it in a shell:

```
/usr/bin/ssh pi@192.168.25.144 \
    /usr/bin/scp /home/pi/"${1}"  \
      '"home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/New\\ Files/"'
```

This takes care of the "New Files" part, but let's also try to do something about the "${1}" argument:

```
/usr/bin/ssh pi@192.168.25.144 \
    /usr/bin/scp /home/pi/"$(printf "%q" "$1")"  \
      '"home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/New\\ Files/"'
```

---

Here's a complete, self contained example of the above, going through localhost twice:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
mkdir "New Files"
touch "my file"
set -- "my file"  # Assign $1="my file"
/usr/bin/ssh localhost \
      /usr/bin/scp "$(printf "%q" "$1")"  \
        '"localhost:New\\ Files/"'

find "New Files" -type f
```

The output shows that it did in fact copy a file with spaces over scp over ssh to the dir with spaces:

```
New Files/my file
```

Since multilevel escaping is tricky, if you're having any problems, make sure to try this self contained example first without modifications before concluding that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Put "" around the path.

```
$ mkdir 1 1
mkdir: 1: File exists
$ mkdir "1 1"
$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  2 mikael  staff  68 May 21 22:35 1
drwxr-xr-x  2 mikael  staff  68 May 21 22:36 1 1
```

Comment: Using quotes around the path did not work. Using quotes and backslash gave me this error: scp: "ambiguous target".

Comment: If it doesn't work with quotes and a single backslash, try with double baskslash like this:

    scp testfile remote.host:"~/test\\ test/"

Comment: Tested this: home@192.X.X.X:"/Users/home/Documents/New\\ Files/"  and  home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/"New\\ Files"/ and both did not work.

Comment: I tested my suggestion above which worked for me. Which error do you get? Try adding -v for verbose mode.

Comment: I get: "scp: ambiguous target"

Comment: Try like this. It also works for me: scp testfile 'remote.host:~/"test test"/'

Comment: Third thing that works for me, triple backslash: scp testfile remote.host:~/test\\\ test/

Comment: Error again. Maybe this works directly on Terminal, but not using NSTask and NSPipe, which is how I am using.

Comment: My guess is you also need to escape it from your program making it triple escaped since both the local and receiving shell will remove one escaping. Something like 5 backslashes \\\\\ before each space.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping spaces with a backslash:

```
home@192.X.X.X:/Users/home/Documents/New\ Files/
```